# Convert PartialView Html to String for ITextSharp HtmlParser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, itext, mvchtmlstring

I've got a partial view, i'm trying to use ITextSharp to convert the html to pdf. How can I convert the html to string so I can use ItextSharps HtmlParser?

I've tried something like this with no luck...any ideas?:

```
 var contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Url.Action("myPartial", "myController", new { id = 1 }, "http"));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a special ViewResult class that you can return as the result of an Action.

You can see the code on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/gvs/imvcpdf/src) (look at the PdfFromHtmlResult class).

So what it basically does is:

- Render the view through the Razor engine (or any other registered engine) to Html
- Give the html to iTextSharp
- return the pdf as the ViewResult (with correct mimetype, etc).

My ViewResult class looks like:

```
 public class PdfFromHtmlResult : ViewResult {

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ViewName)) {
            this.ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        if (this.View == null) {
            this.View = this.FindView(context).View;
        }

        // First get the html from the Html view
        using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
            var vwContext = new ViewContext(context, this.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, writer);
            this.View.Render(vwContext, writer);

            // Convert to pdf

            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            using (var pdfStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                var pdfDoc = new Document(); 
                var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, pdfStream);

                pdfDoc.Open();

                using (var htmlRdr = new StringReader(writer.ToString())) {

                    var parsed = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(htmlRdr, null);

                    foreach (var parsedElement in parsed) {
                        pdfDoc.Add(parsedElement);
                    }
                }

                pdfDoc.Close();

                response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", this.ViewName + ".pdf");
                byte[] pdfBytes = pdfStream.ToArray();
                response.OutputStream.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

With the correct extension methods (see BitBucket), etc, the code in my controller is something like:

```
 public ActionResult MyPdf(int id) {
       var myModel = findDataWithID(id);

       // this assumes there is a MyPdf.cshtml/MyPdf.aspx as the view
       return this.PdfFromHtml(myModel);
 }
```

*Note*: Your method does not work, because you will retrieve the Html on the server, thereby you loose all cookies (=session information) that are stored on the client.

Comment: would this work with a view not created using the Razor engine?

Comment: I didn't test without razor, but I also don't reference Razor. I expect that the ViewContext is intelligent enough to use another renderer when needed.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a shot...I'm getting a compile error "Cannot implicitly convert iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter to System.IDisposable" on these 2 lines:  using (var pdfDoc = new Document()) 
        using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, pdfStream))

Comment: Strange, maybe, you have another iTextSharp version? I'll change the code example to not use the `using`, since `pdfDoc.Close` is explicitly called, they are not 100% needed, just nicer.

Comment: Ok, great! One last issue: return this.PdfFromHtml(myModel); doesn't seem to work for some reason :( It doesn't resolve PdfFromHtml, i've got all references, using itextxharp 4.1.6, MyPdf in my case is an ascx or partial view...any ideas?

Comment: Also add the ControllerExtension class from the BitBucket site (https://bitbucket.org/gvs/imvcpdf/src/d4131aa15b45/iMvcPdf/ControllerExtensions.cs). I'm using the bitbucket code myself, so bitbucket is also where updates will appear.

Comment: Excellent solution!. Any possibility this can be converted to use partial views?