# Illegal character in path using iTextSharp in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

I'm attempting to use the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953604/convert-partialview-html-to-string-for-itextsharp-htmlparser?answertab=active#tab-top) for generating a pdf document from a view, but keep getting the "Illegal character in path" error when I get to this line:

```
var parsed = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(htmlRdr, null);
```

The view I am returning contains multiple partial views and uses a master page, if it helps.  Any thoughts on how to protect the html during parsing?

Comment: @SLaks: ` at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str) at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it need add an image provider:

```
pdfDoc.Open();
Dictionary<string, object> providers = new Dictionary<string, object> {};
providers.Add("img_baseurl", Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + 
Request.Url.Authority);
htmlparser.SetProviders(providers);
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
```